# How do you put a guard statement inside a function in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, cocoa-touch

I don't understand why you can't have a guard statement inside of a returning function.

```
func sayHello(text: String?) -> String {
    guard let whatever = text else {
        ...
        return
    }
    return "aString"
}
```

Why is the above incorrect? Xcode gives me the error "non-void function should return a value" on the `return` statement in the `guard` closure, like it thinks that `return` statement is the function's `return` statement. How do you differentiate between a `guard`'s `return` statement and the function's `return` statement?

The same thing happens in completion handlers that do not return:

```
func anotherFunction() -> Bool {
    aFunction("hello", completion: { (status) -> Void in
        if status == "good" {
            return true // I want anotherFunction() to return this not the handler
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

Xcode thinks that I am trying to have a void completion handler return a `Bool`, instead I want the function to return a `Bool` based on the result of the completion handler.

I think I understand why you can't do this in the completion handler example, but you should definitely be able to have a guard statement inside a non-void function. I tried replacing `return` (in the `guard` example) with `break` and `continue`, neither of which worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whole point here is...you can't return inside the execution of a completion handler. In your second case, if you want to return a boolean about the result of your completion handler, you'll have to make a local variable, set it in the result of your handler, and then return that outside of the handler. As for the first problem you're facing, Xcode is complaining because you've declared the function as returning a string, yet in your else statement you're trying to return void, which violates the return type of the function. You can do what you're trying to do, but you have to return at least an empty string.

Comment: If I return an empty string then that means the function will stop executing. What if I just want to execute out of a guard statement but not out of the entire function?

Comment: Then leave the `else` blank. No code, nothing to execute, moving on. But I would be remiss if I didn't point out that doing this kind of makes the guard statement useless. It's supposed to be for checking the integrity of your data, but if you check it and the result is unsuccessful, but then want to continue execution, I don't see the point of the guard in the first place.

Comment: You can't leave it blank. Guard's must have transfer control.

Comment: Well then if you really want it to not do anything, then I would recommend changing your function to check your data in a different way based on what I said above.

Comment: The function is more complicated than my example. The function is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it returns a `UITableViewCell`. The point of the guard is to check if a file exists at a URL. If it doesn't exist (the else) I need to set the `UIImageView` in the cell to something, and if it does exist then I can set the image to the file retrieved from the URL. I don't want the function to return if the file doesn't exist because there's still more to execute after the guard.

Comment: Right okay, that makes sense. But if this is the case you can just use `if let` which will then allow you to take the else case also. The `guard` statement is more commonly used at the beginning of functions that do some sort of data manipulation and need to make sure the data is there before trying to access it.

Comment: @Jake: You *can* put a `guard` statement inside a `do`-block, and then the else case breaks out of the do-block instead of returning from  the function. But `if let` is much simpler ...